# ElastifcSearch UpdateByQueryRequest from 6.2 to 7.4.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I have to upgrade our ES from 6.2 (TCP client) to 7.4.2 (REST API)

And I have a little problem with `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder`, that looks like need to be change to `UpdateByQueryRequest` ([doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html)). The **old** code looks like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder dateQueryBuilder = ...
QueryBuilder a = ...
BoolQueryBuilder b = ...

UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = new UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder(tcpClient, UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE);
updateByQuery.filter(dateQueryBuilder.filter(a).filter(b)).script(updateScript);
```

As I wrote, I'm understanding `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` (that using the oldest client) should be replace with `UpdateByQueryRequest` **but** this new API haven't `filter` method (just `setQuery` that will replace the current query in chain case...)

```
UpdateByQueryRequest updateRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest();
updateRequest.setQuery(dateQueryBuilder)
    // .setQuery(a) - will replace dateQueryBuilder instead of chain new filter...
    // .filter - not exist in the new API
```

So the question, how should I replace this code with newest ES REST API (or chain the queries)?

Comment: Why do you want to replace `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` by `UpdateByQueryRequest`? [`UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder.filter()` calls `UpdateByQueryRequest.setQuery()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/reindex/AbstractBulkByScrollRequestBuilder.java#L64-L67) underneath.

Comment: @Val, first Thank you! I want to use `RestHighLevelClient` instaed of the old client, as I understand I need to replce `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` by `UpdateByQueryRequest`. The code in your link only doing set, but not adding new filter like here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/08bf0aed43c682b57a65223d74513a9682c381eb/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.java#L128-L134... I need to concatenate `dateQueryBuilder`, `a` and `b`...

Comment: `filter` is not called on `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` but on `dateQueryBuilder` (since it's a bool query) that is then added via `setQuery` on `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder`.

Comment: @Val, Thank you very very much!!! I missed it

Comment: @Val. can you add your answer please.

Comment: @Jacob, it's looks like this `.setQuery(dateQueryBuilder.filter(a).filter(b))`